# Mahout trust aware collaborative filtering

Tags: mahout, collaborative-filtering, trust

I'm trying develop a trust-aware collaborative filtering approach. I have two epinions datasets. One with who trusts who: `<ID_truster, ID_trusted>`. And one with ratings: `<ID_truster, ITEM, RATING>`.

How can I make recommendations (User-User based) using only ratings from people who I trust?

At the moment I only make recommendations using the second dataset, taking in consideration every user.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I can think of is to use a user-neighborhood-based approach, and only include trusted users in the neighborhood. You would need to write some extra code for that, to disqualify untrusted users, by returning a very negative similarity value for them. Look at the `UserSimilarity` interface.

Comment: So If I want to to get predictions from users with common ratings using tanimotoCoefficientSimilarity e.g I would go straight to that class to sort trusted users?  THANK YOU!